# Instanciate a bean with singleton scope

Tags: java, spring, singleton

When the bean below will be instanciated ?

```
<bean id="a" class="Someclass" lazy-init="true" scope="singleton"/>
```

Does Spring ignore the "lazy-init" attribute in this case (because we use singleton scope) ?

A new instance will be created once when the bean definition is loaded. Could anyone comfirm that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This

```
<bean id="a" class="Someclass" lazy-init="true" scope="singleton"/>
```

and this

```
<bean id="a" class="Someclass" lazy-init="true"/>
```

are same. The default scope of spring bean is singleton. And so it definitely does not ignore this attributee.

`lazy-init="true"` won't create your bean on start-up. Your beans will be created only when requested.

Answer (score 0):

> Does Spring ignore the "lazy-init" attribute in this case (because we
>   use singleton scope)?

No, it doesn't ignore, the object will be created only when it is accessed first time, rather than during the container start up.

> A new instance will be created once when the bean definition is
>   loaded. Could anyone confirm that?

No, the instance will be created only when the bean is actually required.

You can refer the same point in spring doc from [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-lazy-init) and below is the text (emphasis mine)

> A lazy-initialized bean tells the IoC container to create a bean
>   instance **when it is first requested, rather than at startup**. **However, when a lazy-initialized bean is a dependency of a singleton bean that is not lazy-initialized, the ApplicationContext creates the lazy-initialized bean at startup**, because it must satisfy the singleton’s dependencies. The lazy-initialized bean is injected into a singleton bean elsewhere that is not lazy-initialized.